# How to put buttons on center with swift code using Xcode 7 Beta?

Tags: swift, autolayout, xcode7

I made a game with Xcode 7 Beta, I put some buttons but they don't arrange as it's supposed, On some iPhones they stay on the left on some other iPhones they stay on the right, and It's supposed to stay on center.

> This is on iPhone 5/5s and how is supposed to be[image]
>
> This is on iPhone 4s[image]
>
> This is on iPhone 6
>   [image]

And the code that I used is:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    leaderboard()
    facebookShare()
    twitterShare()
    removeAds()
}




func leaderboard() {
   let myNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "buttonLeaderboard")

    myNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(120 + BUTTON_WIDTH + BUTTON_SPACING), y: view!.frame.maxY * 0.25)
    myNode.size = CGSizeMake(80.0, 40.0)
    self.addChild(myNode)
}


func facebookShare() {
    let facebookShareNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "buttonFacebookShare")
    facebookShareNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(130 + BUTTON_WIDTH * 2 + BUTTON_SPACING * 2), y: view!.frame.maxY * 0.25)
    facebookShareNode.size = CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)
    self.addChild(facebookShareNode)
}


func twitterShare() {
    let twitterShareNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "buttonTwitterShare")
    twitterShareNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(180 + BUTTON_WIDTH * 2 + BUTTON_SPACING * 2), y: view!.frame.maxY * 0.25)
    twitterShareNode.size = CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)
    self.addChild(twitterShareNode)
}

func removeAds() {
    let removeAdsNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "buttonRemoveAds")
    removeAdsNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(250 + BUTTON_WIDTH * 2 + BUTTON_SPACING * 2), y: view!.frame.maxY * 0.25)
    removeAdsNode.size = CGSizeMake(80.0, 40.0)
    self.addChild(removeAdsNode)
}
```

I hope You can help me what I missed.

Comment: take a view and place your all button in that view and use horizontal center for view

Comment: Can You show me code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [Autolayout's constraints mechanism](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to define the desired location of these buttons on different screens. Otherwise you might end up in unneeded and complicated calculations of widths and offsets just to position few elements in the view.

You can group those buttons in a UIView element and center the element using constraints.

Example of setting central horizontal and vertical constraints of an element:
[image: center constraints]

Comment: I tried on main.Storyboard but it won't work some buttons became bigger some smaller etc and I watched many tutorials but same. so I choose to put them with code I think it's better.

Comment: Is it possible that you had ambiguous constraint. They are marked with yellow or red arrow next to the name of your View Controller in the Assistant Editor panel of Xcode.

Comment: Can You show me any video ? Please ! (Because I'm beginner)

Comment: I think this is good introductory video and also it shows the "red arrow" I mentioned and how to resolve it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng

Comment: Thanks it was so helpful :)